# Find out the new element in EditText View

Tags: android

I want to execute one method wheneer i enter number in EditText view.But i did not change the focus of EditText.I am stay in the same EditText when i enter a new number automatically i eant to execute one function.Now my question is how we find that event that means enter a new number in EditText

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to your `EditText`, and then, check in `onTextChanged()` if the character added was a number. You could use a [regular expression](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-descr.html) for that :

```
if(s.matches("[0-9]")){
  doYourStuffMethod();
}
```

You can also use the [Matcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class from Android SDK which is an helper for this kind of stuff.